# prevent insert same id if the user/student not put timeout

Tags: php

i have two button on my homepage one is time-in and the other is time-out,
i want to prevent the user/student to time-in using same id if he did not put time-out on his last time-in to create valid entry. Hope you can help me.

here is my php code:

```
<?php 

include_once('connection.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit0'])){
    $rfid = $_POST['rfid'];
    $time=date("H:i:s");
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM stud WHERE rfid_num = '$rfid'");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($sql);

    if ($count == 0 ) {
        header("location:notexist.php");
    } elseif (empty($row['timeout'])) {
        header("location:page say the user/student need to put timeout first before time-in again");
    } else {
        while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
            $rfid=$row['rfid_num'];
            $id=$row['id'];
            $name0 = $row['name'];
            $course0 = $row['course'];
            $image = $row['image'];

            $InsertSql = "INSERT INTO student_att(rfid_num,id,name,course,image,timein) VALUES ('$rfid','$id','$name0','$course0','$image','$time')";
            $res = mysqli_query($conn, $InsertSql); 
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Looks like you're nearly there, you just need to redirect the user back to the form to complete it again? Or if the form is part of the same SQL script as this, you can just let it render the form again instead of redirecting. You also need to actually fetch your data from the student_att table before you try to use it. At the moment $row is not defined.

Comment: i tried to redirect the user back to the form again, but it always redirect to the form even if the user has no record on time-in. @ADyson

Comment: well, like I said, you aren't actually asking the database for any info about the time record as far as I can see.

Comment: @ADyson if joinig the two table it is possible to work ? join student_att at the select query ?

Comment: yes but you would get multiple rows, unless you specify in the clause that it only fetches the most recent record from student_att - I assume that's what you want?

Comment: @ADyson can you help me where i place the select queary for the student attendance if i dont join the two tables ?

Comment: A join would be fine. Either way you'd need the same WHERE clause to get only the last attendance record, so it would make more sense to do it like that. Then just read the first row (if you're only expecting one row, you can replace your `while` with `if`) to get the time in / out field and then decide what to do.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for the idea you give me , i manage work my code , just little bit try and error. :)

Comment: No problem. Great that you managed to solve it. You know, you should write your new code as the answer, with a little explanation of the changes. You can "accept" your own answers, and others looking for similar solutions can use it, and may choose to upvote it

Comment: you are right about im not selecting the table of student_att that way the code empty($row[column'' ] not working.

Answer (score 2):

this is my answer just wanna share it, i just add select  student_att table
to fetch the data and check if timeout column is empty.

```
<?php 

include_once('connection.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit0'])){
$rfid = $_POST['rfid'];
$time=date("H:i:s");
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from stud where rfid_num ='$rfid' ");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
if ($count == 0) {
            header("location:notexist.php");
        }else{
         while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                  $rfid=$row['rfid_num'];
                  $id=$row['id'];
                   $name0 = $row['name'];
                       $course0 = $row['course'];
                    $image = $row['image'];

                $sql1 = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from student_att where rfid_num ='$rfid' order by number DESC limit 1 ");
                 while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql1)) {

             if(empty($row['timeout'])){
                   header("location:logout.php");
                 }else{


         $InsertSql = "INSERT INTO student_att(rfid_num,id,name,course,image,timein) VALUES ('$rfid','$id','$name0','$course0','$image','$time')";
        $res = mysqli_query($conn, $InsertSql); 
        }
        }

        }

}
}
?>
```